# Subprocess not working when called in atom

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, atom-editor

I am running python3.6 in Atom using the package 'script' on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am trying to cut videos using [ffpb](https://pypi.org/project/ffpb/) (basically ffmpeg with a progress bar instead of verbose).

The following code gives the error: *'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffpb': 'ffpb'*

```
import subprocess

cmds = ['ffpb', '-i', 'input.mp4', 'output.mp4']
subprocess.call(cmds)
```

- The command 'ffpb -i input.mp4 output.mp4' works in the terminal
- The script works when I call it with python3 in the terminal
- The script works in atom if I replace ffpb by ffmpeg
- I installed ffpb using pip3 install --user ffpb
- I never had problems like this running code in atom before.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks, but subprocess.call by default expects a list like in the example above. I tried it anyway and it doesn't work even when I ran it outside atom.